# Detect which element is moused over and pass to function

Tags: javascript, svg, mouseover, gsap

I'm using greensock to animate an svg clippath, and it works great with one clippath, and hardcoded variables. Now I'm needing to add more clippaths, and I need each one to animate independently. So I need to build some sort of function to detect which circle is being moused over/ moused out and then call the timeline, passing it the correct parameters (the clippath and overlay circle). I'm sure I could probably do that with 'this' but I'm still at the point where 'this' makes my brain melt. Here's the codepen I'm working on.

http://codepen.io/kathryncrawford/pen/JYvdzx

HTML

```
  <svg class="svg-graphic" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clippath">
  <circle id="clip1" cx="200" cy="200" r="2.5"/>
  <circle id="clip2" cx="400" cy="200" r="3.2"/>  
  </clipPath>
</defs>
<image class="svg-image1" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" width="300" height="300" x="80" y="80"/>
<circle id="circle1"  fill="#CC66FF" cx="200" cy="200" r="30"/>

<image class="svg-image2" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" width="300" height="300" x="380" y="80"/>
<circle id="circle2" fill="#CC66FF" cx="400" cy="200" r="30"/>
```

JS

```
var clip = document.getElementById("clip1");
var circles = document.getElementById("circle1");

circles.addEventListener("mouseenter", expand);
circles.addEventListener("mouseleave", contract);

var tl = new TimelineMax({paused: true});
tl.to(clip, 0.5, {
    attr: {
      r: 120
    },
    transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
    ease: Power4.easeInOut
  })
  .to(circles, 0.5, {alpha:0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, '-0.1');

function expand() {
  tl.play();
}

function contract() {
  tl.reverse();
}
```

Comment: Here is what `this` is inside an event listener; it's the element you are adding the event to, in this case "circles" (the element with the id "circle1"). That simple. Now you know one proper usage of `this`, and your brain is still cool, most probably.

Comment: Haha, maybe a little warm. But any way I could use 'this' to denote both the circle AND the clip that goes along with it?

Comment: `this` will just refer to the "circle1". Maybe you will have give class names to all circles for example, and use `for loop` (at least that is what I am trying right now), I will update. Also I have zero experience with `SVG`s, wait please.

Comment: I tried the `for loop` approach, but the solution is not complete. Check; [JSFiddle - link](http://jsfiddle.net/m31ctr3b/).

Comment: Take a look at **[this](http://codepen.io/tah_med/full/BoVLJP/)**. I'll put it as an answer later and will mention all the details with it but for now, I suggest you to try to understand what is happening in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, **[this](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/BoVLJP?editors=001)** is what I was able to create by forking your pen.

And here is what has changed:

- In **HTML**, I have removed unique *IDs* set on each of the `circle` HTML elements present inside the `clipPath` HTML element i.e. `clipPath`'s children. Instead, I have given all of these `circle` tags a `clip` class.
- The other `circle` elements that are siblings of the said `clipPath` i.e. present on the same level as `clipPath` element, have been given a `circle` class.
- And as for the `image` elements, I have done similar thing. Removed unique *IDs* from them and instead gave them a common `svg-image` class.
- This is HTML done.
- In HTML, since the unique *IDs* have been removed such as `#circle1`, `#circle2`, `#svg-image1` and `#svg-image2`, I have removed them from **CSS** as well and instead applied exactly the same rules they had on the newly created classes i.e. `.circle` and `.svg-image` respectively.
- In **JavaScript**, the `clip` and `circle` elements as well as the total number of `clip` elements are first stored in variables `clips`, `circles` and `numClips` respectively.
- There is also an empty array of `timelines` created initially.
- Then there is a loop being initiated which goes up till the length of `numClips` and which does two things:

  - `createTimeline` as the name suggests, is supposed to create a `TimelineMax` instance which looks similar to what you previously had i.e. it adds two tweens, one for animating the `opacity` on the current `circle` element (remember, we are inside a loop and we have a reference of current `circle` element by the use of `circles[i]`) and the other for animating `r` of the current `clip` element.
  - `assignListeners` is for listening to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on each of the `circle` elements.
- And finally, `expand` and `collapse` methods are for playing or reversing the current timeline instance. (again, we have the reference of the `timeline` that should be playing when hovered or out using `timelines[i]` reference).

**HTML:**

```
<svg class="svg-graphic" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clippath">
      <circle class="clip" cx="200" cy="200" r="20" />
      <circle class="clip" cx="400" cy="200" r="20" />
      <circle class="clip" cx="600" cy="200" r="20" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image class="svg-image" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" width="300" height="300" x="80" y="80" />
  <circle class="circle" fill="#CC66FF" cx="200" cy="200" r="20" />
  <image class="svg-image" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" width="300" height="300" x="380" y="80" />
  <circle class="circle" fill="#CC66FF" cx="400" cy="200" r="20" />
  <image class="svg-image" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" width="300" height="300" x="680" y="80" />
  <circle class="circle" fill="#CC66FF" cx="600" cy="200" r="20" />
</svg>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0  
}

.circle{        
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  clip-path: url("#clippath");
}

.svg-image {
  z-index: 3;
  clip-path: url(#clippath);
}

svg{
    overflow: visible;
}

.svg-graphic {
  position: absolute;
}

.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var clips = document.getElementsByClassName('clip');
var circles = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
var numClips = clips.length;
var timelines = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numClips; i += 1) {
  createTimeline(i);
  assignListeners(i);
}

function createTimeline(i) {
  var timeline = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
  timeline.to(circles[i], 0.6, { opacity: 0, ease: Expo.easeInOut }, 0);
  timeline.to(clips[i], 0.6, {
    attr: { r: 120 },
    transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
    ease: Expo.easeInOut
  }, 0.1);
  timelines[i] = timeline;
}

function assignListeners(i) {
  (function(i) {
    circles[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) { expand(e, i); }, false);
    circles[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) { contract(e, i); }, false);
  }(i));
}

function expand(e, i) { timelines[i].play(); }
function contract(e, i) { timelines[i].reverse(); }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whoa, that's beautiful. That's EXACTLY what I was trying to do. Thanks so much for your help!!!